# Pushing json file into a localStorage array

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I have a task to make CRUD app in angular 8 but I have to push somehow my JSON file into local storage and then be able to add new objects. I made an array of contacts and put some data in there and if someone can help me to put this JSON data in that array of objects, so I can read all my contacts from localStorage.
I have tried to subscribe to contacts and it kinda works but won't add data to a localStorage. [image: When i add manualy object it adds to a localstorage]

**Contacts Service**

```js
import { Contact } from '../models/contact';
import { IContact } from '../models/contact';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ContactService {

  contacts: Array < Contact > = [{
    first_name: "Darko",
    last_name: "Lesevic",
    emails: ["darko1@test.com", "darko2@test.com"],
    phones: [123456789, 123456789, 123456789],
    photo: ''
  }];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

    //this won't work

    // this.getJSON().subscribe(data => { 
    //   this.contacts = data;
    //   console.log(data); 
    //   });

  }

  getJSON(): Observable < Contact[] > {
    return this.http.get < Contact[] > ("/assets/data/contacts.json");
  }

  contacts_serialized: any;
  contacts_deserialized: any;

  localStorageObj() {
    this.contacts_serialized = JSON.stringify(this.contacts); //converts data to string

    localStorage.setItem('id', this.contacts_serialized);

    this.contacts_deserialized = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id')); //converts string to data
    console.log(this.contacts_deserialized);
  }

}
```

**Calling contact Service here**

```js
import { ContactService } from '../services/contact.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Contact } from '../models/contact';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private contactService: ContactService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  this.contactService.localStorageObj();
    
  }

}
```

**MY JSON FILE**

```js
[{
  "first_name": "Afonso",
  "last_name": "Pinto",
  "emails": ["mail01@gmail.com", "mail02@gmail.com"],
  "phones": ["123-234-566", "123-234-567", "123-234-568"],
  "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/400/300/people/"
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Alexandre",
  "last_name": "Paiva",
  "emails": ["mail01@gmail.com"],
  "phones": ["123-234-560", "123-234-561"],
  "photo": null
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Oea",
  "last_name": "Romana",
  "emails": ["mail01@gmail.com", "mail02@gmail.com"],
  "phones": ["123-234-566", "123-234-567", "123-234-568"],
  "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/400/300/people/"
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Nuria",
  "last_name": "Pelayo",
  "emails": ["mail01@gmail.com", "mail02@gmail.com"],
  "phones": ["123-234-568"],
  "photo": "http://lorempixel.com/400/300/people/"
 },
 {
  "first_name": "Lisandro",
  "last_name": "Matos",
  "emails": ["mail01@gmail.com", "mail02@gmail.com"],
  "phones": ["123-234-566", "123-234-567"],
  "photo": null
 }
]
```

Comment: If you are thinking to mutate the localstorage value, then it is not possible. Since it only stores the string values and even string values cannot be mutated in localstorage. Fetch localstorage value first and then convert it to an Array. Now concat it with new set of contacts. Store new array back as a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to subscribe and then use **`setItem`**

```
this.contactService.getJSON().subscribe((data) => {
  localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

Comment: Okey but how can i push it to the same localStorage array? When i setItem 'id' it override existing array in localStorage. I want to put them in one array. When i setItem 'id2' there are two arrays in the localStorage.

Comment: I have fixed it `code` this.getJSON().subscribe(data => {
      let a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('contacts')); 
      localStorage.setItem('contacts', JSON.stringify(data));

      localStorage.setItem('contactObject', JSON.stringify(this.contacts));
      a.push(this.contacts)
      localStorage.setItem('contacts',  JSON.stringify(a));
    });